# Add float[] array to a list<float[]> and clear contents of array without losing the list contents

Tags: c#

In C#, how can I copy contents of a float[] array () to a list<float[]> such that when I clear the float[] array, the contents of the list<float[]> is not touched (i.e. a copy)?
Some script is provided in the attached picture where:

1. there are 21 points whose values increase by 0.5 starting at 0 and ending in 10.
2. The ceiling of this point value, gives a suffix for 32 bit binary file for instance when the point value is 0.5 or 1, binary file "File1.bin" will be used in the calculations while for point value 1.5 and 2, binary file "File2.bin" will be used and so forth.
3. Each file is a 32 bit float-point binary with a fixed number of elements when read as 32 bit binary values.
4. I want to go over all the points (in a for loop), and if I have not read a binary file for that point, read the contents of the file and save it in a list. Since the file is read into a float[] array ("oneFile" variable in the script), my incremental list is List<float[]> (variable "allFiles" in the script).
5. At the end of each iteration in the for loop, I'd like to clear the contents of the array "oneFile" and read into it potentially in the future iteration. However, this obviously also clears the contents of  "allFiles". How can I avoid this?

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHpLT.png)

Comment: `list.Add(array.ToArray());` we create a *copy* of the initial `array` with a help of `ToArray()` and then `Add` this copy to the `list`

Comment: Please post your code, not a screenshot.

Comment: Don't clear the `float[]`, set it to a new instance of a `float[]` (so it's not referring to the same one you added to the list).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clearing the array with [`Array.Clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clear?view=netcore-3.1), which just sets a range of elements in an array to the default value of each element type, you should set `oneFile` to a *new instance* of an array, so it's no longer referring to the same instance we just added to `allFiles`.

In other words,

- replace: `Array.Clear(oneFile, 0, oneFile.Length);`

  - (this just assignes all the items to `0`)
- with: `oneFile = new float[FileSizeBytes / 4];`

  - (this changes the reference to a new array populated with items initialized to `0`)